# Handle reversed locale name with gatsby localization (eg. us-en instead of en-us)

Tags: reactjs, localization, react-router, internationalization, gatsby

I have a use case where I need to revamp a landing page that was on wordpress to Gatsby which is well reference in Google and all, but with a wrong locales names (site.com/us-en/some-route-url) instead of (site.com/en-us/some-route-url).

The issue is that in my config file if I do

```
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-intl`,
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/intl`,
        languages: [`us-en`, `ma-ar`],
        defaultLanguage: `us-en`,
        redirect: true,
      },
    },
```

it gives error of **can't find locale "us-en" in react-inlt/locale-data.** and when I just reverse it to

`` languages: [`en-us`, `ar-ma`], ``

it works, but I need the first usecase of **us-en** to work to maintain the old URL format of the landing page and therefore not hurt the SEO.

How can I make this locale format accepted by this plugin or with some custom routing in **Gatsby** or something ?

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@musicformellons ended up that lang-country (ie. en-us ) is the correct format of internationalizations you can't ask the plugin to reverse it. Otherwise I asked an SEO expert and he said switching website url from /us-en to /en-us won't affect the website SEO nor position on google as long as a 301 permanent redirection is applied.